# API Gateway not returning correct template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Having some weird AWS issue with mapping templates. My lambda either returns a json body or a 404. When the lambda returns a body this template works as intended but on the 404 I get nothing back when I’m expecting that "message": "test" from

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "message" : "test"
}
```

My guess is that first line but nothing I change is giving me the desired result. My assumption so far is that since there's nothing being returned with the 404 it never substitutes this. Any ideas?

Edit: the 404 is coming from S3 directly through an integration request rather than a Lambda because it couldn't find anything to return. Rather than just pass that 404 to the customer we want to pass a message as well with details.

Comment: What body template you set ?

Comment: I set the one above. It works for when the lambda returns a 200, but not anything else. I really need it for those other status codes.

Comment: 404 is your code level custom code you are passing ? add same code you trying

Comment: yea. But instead of just returning 404 to the customer I want to also pass a custom message back.

Comment: Can you just add your both case details. 404 is not found resource this come when you trying to access API or path which doesn't exist. If you want to add custom code your handle in your code differently.

Comment: I'll add an edit, but the 404 is coming from S3 directly through an integration request rather than a Lambda because it couldn't find anything to return. Rather than just pass that 404 to the customer we want to pass a message as well with details.

Comment: where is S3 comes from ? that why i am asking to give full details.

Comment: Gateway sends a request to S3 for a file. If it doesn't exist S3 returns 404 which gets passed to the customer.